# Origin: Spirits of the Past - Any ideas on who makes the 'phone call'

Tags: plot-explanation, origin-spirits-of-past

In [Origin: Spirits of the Past](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origin%3a_Spirits_of_the_Past), Toola at the beginning receives a (what can only be called) a phonecall which she doesn't end up answering.

From memory, Shunack claims he didn't make the call, but did he really make the call or is this Gonzo's attempt at saying their are possible others, or could it have been the forest itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shunack did indeed make the call. Somehow he was able to detect that her Raban was active (possibly when she used it to open that door to escape the water). Notice that Shunack knows before Minka makes it aware to the soldiers of Toola's presence in the restaurant/bar.

After Toola talks to Agito's father she wanders off (on her way to the forest?) and is *somehow* encountered by Shunack. Seeing that he had more than one Raban, I can only guess that he made previous attempts to open E.S.T.O.C. with the Rabans found on the dead bodies in the cryogenic pods.

Comment: That sounds likely, it's been a little while, but at the end doesn't her Raban activate again after she throws it away or am I making that up?

Comment: @Skud It falls deep in the ruins then it goes into credits. The movie is on YouTube legally if you would like to watch it again. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jn69yXVasc

Answer (score 0):

A Raban can only be activated by its owner; Shunack said he had lost his years ago. The ones he wore were no good to him or he would have activated the E.S.T.O.C. without Toola.

I would say there are others out there.